# Analytic continuation of function differentiable on real line to complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity

If $f(z)=g(z)$ on $(0, \infty)$ and f(z) is holomorphic on an open set $U \subset \mathbf{C}$ with $(0, \infty) \subset U$, but we do not have any information about where $g(z)$ is holomorphic, can we still analytically continue $g(z)$ to $U$ ?

Normally we apply analytic continuations to two functions that are known to be holomorphic in open subsets of the plane, but what if we only know that one of them is holomorphic in an open subset.  In my example it follows that since $f(z)$ is holomorphic at any positive real number that $g(z)$ is differentiable on the real line, but that's the only conclusion I can draw.

Comment: I think what you are _really_ asking is whether we can have information about $g$ on $U$ just by knowing it is continuous there and that its restriction on the real line matches that of a holomorphic function. The answer is not really.., continuity is a much wilder beast than analyticity...

Comment: Say we have an explicit definition of g and f and we know that g is well-defined in U. Could it be possible that f, a holomorphic function, happens to agree with g on the real line, but f does not equal g in the rest of U? Thus, g would not be holomorphic anywhere, but only differentiable, in the real sense, on the real line?

Comment: Yes of course. Think of this: Pick a very very weird _continuous_ function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (say nowhere differentiable) such that $h(0)=0$. Now define $g(a+bi)=f(a)+h(b)i\quad $     (for $a$ and $b$ real numbers) . I think it is easy to see that $g$ is differentiable on the real line (actually on every horizontal line) but it is most definitely not homolomorphic.., anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a bit strange (or it is not clear to me what is your question). Strictly speaking, the information you have given about $f$ means that it is analytic on $U$ and it is an extension of $g$ to $U$.

The values of a function at a set of points that accumulate at a finite point $a$ are enough to determine the germ (the series at $a$) of an analytic function.

The positive real axis accumulates at any of its points. If there is an analytic function equal to $g$ there is only one near each point of $(0,\infty)$. We are told $f$ is that function.

Comment: Say we have an explicit definition of g and f and we know that g is well-defined in U.  Could it be possible that f, a holomorphic function, happens to agree with g on the real line, but f does not equal g in the rest of U?  Thus, g would not be holomorphic anywhere, but only differentiable, in the real sense, on the real line?

Comment: @nick Ah, you are asking what Theo was suggesting. Then $f$ is not necessarily analytic continuation of $g|_{(0,\infty)}$. But you can still get info about the smoothness of $g$ on the line by means of $f$.

Comment: Ok.  What exactly do you mean by smoothness?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what information of the smoothness of g on the real line we get from f?

Comment: @nick Well, since $f$ has derivatives of all orders, so does $g$. More than that, since $f$ has convergent Taylor series at all points in $(0,\infty)$ so does $g|_{(0,\infty)}$.